# How is the state "undone/reverted" after a longer chain is determined?

Tags: consensus, forks

So say there is block_a, and block_b, both at height 1677. And a node accepts block_a, but then recieves block_b + block_c (which is mined on top of block_b), how exactly are the state changes made in block_a undone and reverted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you will not revert but build on a previous state instead.

Let's suppose you have the states S<sub>n</sub> for block n. Each state only has the changes in that block and a reference to their parent, for example S<sub>101</sub> points to S<sub>100</sub>. The main chain will be S<sub>101</sub> -> S<sub>100</sub> -> S<sub>99</sub> -> ...

To check the balace of an address at block 101: Search address in S<sub>101</sub>, if the address exists return balance and stop. If doesn't exists search recursively in S<sub>100</sub>, S<sub>99</sub>, ...

Now suppose you have block 101' that will replace previous block. It will generate S<sub>101'</sub> that points to S<sub>100</sub>. After block 102 the main chain will be S<sub>102</sub> -> S<sub>101'</sub> -> S<sub>100</sub>.

Orphan states like S<sub>101</sub> can be discarded if they are no longer referenced by new blocks.

Comment: Ok so if i understand correctly, each block also has the data of all the states that were changed before it was run. Then if an orphan (lets say for extreme example), is 30 blocks long, the node will go backwards through each block und revert to the previous state that is one block less than itself, until it gets to the block that the valid chain is referencing.

Comment: @cookiekid States that are no longer valid are not explicitly reverted they are just ignored since new blocks will not reference them, and later they can be pruned if the client support that feature.

Comment: Hm, so lets say i have a variable in a smart contract called x = 1. in block 132, I increase x += 1. How exactly is this done? The node goes to block 131 to see if it contains x's state? And if not, it goes to 130,129, 128 etc. and then increases it?

Comment: For contracts is something similar, but contract's storage has their separate state. If you are executing a contract C at block 132, you wil retrieve from S_132 the root of the state of C, if the contract was last updated at block 90 it will be C_90, from this state you read x, it is 1, now you create C_132 that will have x = 2, and point to C_90. Now in S_132 the state of C is replaced with C_132.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer in your correct usage of the tag `consensus`.

Think about the Ethereum mainnet with thousands of nodes running around the world. A proper re-phrasing of the question would be:

> **Node_1** mines/ holds the top block as block_a at height 1677. Soon, it learns that there is a node **Node_N** in the network which has block_b at height 1677 and also a block called block_c at height 1678.
>   Here's a list-diagram:
>
> **Node_1: ...block_a (height: 1677)**
>
> **Node_N: ...block_b (height: 1677). block_c (height: 1678)**
>
> How does the Node_1 revert back and put on block_b and block_c?

The answer is simple- the nodes in the network use a simple heuristic that ***choose the node with the longest chain in the network.*** So, **Node_1** will drop it's block_a i.e. go back to the state that it had at height 1666. Reverting back is just going back to the desired block number state of the Ethereum Virtual Machine. This is quiet easy, as a matter of fact, if you sync your node in `archive` mode in Geth, you can debug the blockchain at any block number as if that were the height of the blockchain. So **Node_1** will throw away block_a and then it will just catch up with **Node_N** in our scenario and very easily reflect the state of **Node_N** by putting on block_b followed by block_c at appropriate heights in the blockchain.

The real question is- because the Ethereum mainnet is trustless, what if someone tries to 'fake mine' and put false blocks, and that is where Proof of Work (PoW) algorithm comes in. Besides, Node_1 will verify the blocks it will put on top, so no one can actually 'fake mine' as 1. It takes a lot of energy to mine a block 2. A fake block is easily checked and will never be accepted by any node in the network. There is another interesting class of attack called 51% attack, which actually limits the possibility of other miners in the network to mine (but never to 'fake mine' or double spend.)

Here's a very good reference for an overview of the [consensus mechanism in Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/14consensus.asciidoc).

Comment: Yes I understand that. What i was asking, was the exact process in which the node unwinds all of the tx. in the invalidated block. how exactly does it revert the state?

Answer (score 0):

If reorganization occurs, the diff of two block are computed. **State changes made in block_a are reverted by executing the diff of block_a and block_b**:

```
State(block_a)  +  [State(block_b) - State(block_a)]
=
State(block_b)
```

For more information, please refer to: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/23524f8/core/blockchain.go#L2249